# Is there any equivalent to notifydestroyed() on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is there any equivalent to J2ME notifydestroyed() on Blackberry?  Or are lifespans handled completely differently perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifespans are different, more like a traditional Java application -- the program doesn't exit until it calls System.exit().

(You can run MIDlets in the BlackBerry environment, though, but in most cases you'll want to write to the BlackBerry API and use its app model.)